# Get string after array of characters

Tags: flutter, dart

I got a string like this:

```
"{cat: Molly, dog: Feefee}"
```

I want save in a String cat name, and in different String dog name. How can I do it?

I tried manipulating with constant indexes, but I wnt to be sure, the name will be saved properly when there are different names

Comment: is this the response from api or just local data created?

Comment: You're sure your `String` looks like this? This `String` does not look like `Map` or `JSON` string.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for it?

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final a = '{"cat": "Molly", "dog": "Feefee"}';
  final b = json.decode(a);
  final map = Map<String, dynamic>.from(b);

  print(map['cat']);
  print(map['dog']);
}
```

Output:

```
Molly
Feefee
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing some data cleaning so that your data comes out in JSON format. Then you can decode that and convert it to a map. However, if that is not possible. Here is a round a bout way of getting the values you want.

```
String example = "{cat: Molly, dog: Feefee}";
  
var re = RegExp(r'(?<={)(.*)(?=})');
var match = re.firstMatch(example)?.group(0);
  
var splitted = match?.split(",");
  
var cat = splitted?[0].split(":")[1];
print(cat); //prints Molly
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create model from your json.
https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart
just copy paste your json, it will auto generate your model